# How do I enable CPU throttling on an Athlon X2 4200+ under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, throttling, cool-n-quiet

My desktop computer is constantly running at 2200MHz even at idle load, and the fan is always at full speed.

Cool'n'Quiet is enabled in the BIOS, but the options to set the Maximum and Minimum CPU states are missing from the power options on Windows 7 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: What motherboard and processor do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use RMClock program. Even though it has not been updated recently it does support your CPU.

http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml

Comment: Quite helpful when used on older machines running newer versions of Windows.